# Open SelectedItem in new Modal View

Tags: mvvm, selecteditem

I'm trying to use the example from SingletonSean https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KKfRDXCZys
to get Selected Item from ListView and Edit it in modal view.
Can someone help me, I would like to click at person and open a new modal view, something like on picture (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AU-J_-Ydxz5f9n6tjbzlBxQvni0EV-Th/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you have a picture (that does not show code/text) then please upload it here. The editor has an image button where you can upload it.

Comment: If you check youtube link in previous post there is all code where you can see (13:20 minute) part where we can add person. How to get selected person in new view in order to edit it, thanks.

Comment: Ok, but on stackoverflow you have to post all relevant informations (code, description, images if ever needed) here and all external references are just for much more details but not really necessary for the question. Whenever these external reference will die the information here must stay complete. That should not be new to you after 2+ years on this platform

Comment: It is hard to post all code from mentioned example, I'm not sure if my question is clear I do not know how to make what I asked so I have no any code for edit person. As you can see this example, or any other that has listview, I just would like open selected person in new window to update it, thanks for your effort.

Comment: It is up to you to post a valid question here on SO. You should not expect anyone crawling through a bunch of code to get to that small part you are - maybe - interested in and present you a solution which - maybe - is wrong, as it does not fullfill your expectation.

Comment: Is there any example where we can clicking on ListView item select it and edit - update in new modal view window, I have any code because I do not know how to make this, I wouldn't ask if I knew how. Thanks

Comment: And it is impossible for you to build an application that has everything it needs including the ListView except that edit in the modal view (but keeps focused only on that)? And posting the view/viewmodel/models is also impossible to you? I am sure you will get help at some sites where you can hire a freelancer for that.